# BeautifulSoup: Get the class text

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Assuming that the following code:

```
for data in soup.findAll('div',{'class':'value'}):
    print(data)
```

gives the following output:

```
<div class="value">
<p class="name">Michael Jordan</p>
</div>


<div class="value">
<p class="team">Real Madrid</p>
</div>


<div class="value">
<p class="Sport">Ping Pong</p>
</div>
```

I want to create the following dictionary:

```
  Person = {'name': 'Michael Jordan', 'team': 'Real Madrid', 'Sport': 'Ping Pong'}
```

I can get the text using `data.text` but how can I get the text of the `class` in order to name the `keys` of the dictionary(Person[key1],Person[key2] ...)?

Comment: since your output is a valid xml, you can treat it as xml and get values as you want

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You could use the following:

```
content = '''
<div class="value">
<p class="name">Michael Jordan</p>
</div>

<div class="value">
<p class="team">Real Madrid</p>
</div>

<div class="value">
<p class="Sport">Ping Pong</p>
</div>
'''

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(content)

person = {}

for div in soup.findAll('div', {'class': 'value'}):
    person[div.find('p').attrs['class'][0]] = div.text.strip()

print(person)
```

**Output**

```
{'Sport': u'Ping Pong', 'name': u'Michael Jordan', 'team': u'Real Madrid'}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do iit like this:

```
for data in soup.findAll('div',{'class':'value'}):
    person = {}
    for item in data.find_all('div'):
        attr = item.p.attrs.get("class")[0]
        value = item.p.text
        person[attr] = value

    print person
```

Answer (score 1):

Using this snippet

```
soup = <div class="value">
        <p class="Sport other-name-class other">Ping Pong</p>
       </div>

p =  soup.find('div.value p')
```

I found two ways but It is the same, you can use

```
p.get_attribute_list('class')
```

or

```
p.attrs['class']
```

both return array with all class name, like this  `['Sport', 'other-name-class', 'other']`